# Ansible local_action: stat doesnt find my file

Tags: ansible, local, stat

I want to copy a file to remote nodes, but only if the file exists.
I copied it into **/tmp/webapps/partner.war**

My Task is:

```
- local_action: stat path="/tmp/webapps/{{ application }}.war"
  register: war

- name: Copy warfile
  copy: src=/tmp/webapps/{{ application }}.war dest=/tmp/deploy/{{ stage }}/{{ application }}.war
  when: war.stat.exists == true
```

But stat always tells me, the file does not exist. If I run stat manually, it shows me the file is there.

The result:

```
    TASK: [deploy | stat path="/tmp/webapps/{{ application }}.war"] *************** 
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE stat path="/tmp/webapps/partner.war"
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367']
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpzrV_Ne TO /var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367/stat
<127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367/stat; rm -rf /var/lib/awx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433920640.68-144173277081367/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
ok: [example.com -> 127.0.0.1] => {"changed": false, "stat": {"exists": false}}
```

What did I do wrong? :/

Comment: debug the variable `- debug: var=war`

Comment: depending on permissions you also might not be able stat it as your `ansible_user`. Use `sudo: true`

Comment: @xddsg i got it to work, ansible tower uses proot - i deactivated it and now it works

Comment: suggest you make your own answer and make it as solved so it doesn't keeping displaying on the unanswered list :)

Comment: Please, close the question and add your own answer so it cat help other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ansible Tower](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/) uses [PRoot](http://proot.me/) which provides a cool interface for creating `chroot` and similar jails.  In the [Tower docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/2.2.0/html/installandreference/known_issues.html#playbooks-missing-access-to-necessary-data-due-to-proot-issues) they state:

> ## 3.5. Playbooks missing access to necessary data due to PRoot issues
>
> When running a playbook that reads and writes information in certain
>   prohibited directories, users may encounter issues with PRoot. PRoot
>   runs the `ansible-playbook` command within a `chroot` jail. In cases like
>   these, the running playbook cannot see other playbooks or sensitive
>   data on disk and should the playbook expect to have access to that
>   information, problems will occur. To fine tune your usage of PRoot,
>   there are certain variables that can be set:
>
> ```
> # Enable proot support for running jobs (playbook runs only).
> AWX_PROOT_ENABLED = False
>
> # Command/path to proot.
> AWX_PROOT_CMD = 'proot'
>
> # Additional paths to hide from jobs using proot.
> AWX_PROOT_HIDE_PATHS = []
>
> # Additional paths to show for jobs using proot.
> AWX_PROOT_SHOW_PATHS = []
> ```

Comment: Alternatively, you can define /tmp in the Tower setting "paths to expose to isolated jobs". Make sure you really know whether you want this; it's probably not a good idea if your Tower is being used by several teams in the company that are allowed only limited access.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I had similar issues when trying to find files inside the role's 'files' directory (no Tower involved). I'd normally reference these as "../files/something", but that doesn't work for a local_action stat. Instead, this works:

```
- name: check for optional config file
  local_action: stat path={{ role_path }}/files/{{ inventory_hostname }}/some_file
  register: optional_file
```

(so I guess the moral of the story is: use a full path to the local file)

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts!  I could test the role I created and it worked perfectly, but when it was part of the larger playbook it would fail because the stat path was different than the include_vars path.

Answer (score 0):

Another FWIW solution suggested by @ralph-bolton solution. My file lived in the role's 'files' folder and was referenced in a var:

```
vars:
install_root_cert_pem: home-root-ca.crt
```

Was finally found and tested correctly by:

```
local_action: "stat path={{ role_path }}/files/{{ install_root_cert_pem }}"
```